# UISegmentedControl with two UICollectionViews to display images. MULTITHREADING

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

So my goal is to create something like this:

[image]

[image]

My problem is when I switch between segments, I would like to show a UIActivityViewIndicator spinning, as it takes some time to load the images (stored locally so in theory this should be much faster...). But the thread seems to be getting back before switching to the new cells' images.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
- (void)reloadCollection {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    [_myCollection reloadData];
    [_myCollection layoutIfNeeded];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        _spinnerView.hidden = YES;

    });
});
```

}

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlSwitched:(id)sender{

_spinnerView.hidden = NO;

[self reloadCollection];
```

}

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return 1;
```

}

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


if ([_mySegmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 0){
    return [_photosTaken count];
}else
    return [_photosTagged count];
```

}

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UICollectionViewCell *cell;
UIImageView *imageView;

if ([_mySegmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 0){
cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[_photosTaken objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

}
else
{
cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[_photosTagged objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

}

imageView.frame = cell.frame;
[cell setBackgroundView:imageView];
return cell;
```

}

Thanks, 
João Garcia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call UIKit operations on a background thread, unless the documentation explicitly states that you can.

In any case, your problem is not one that should be solved simply by throwing things on a background thread.

You say yourself, **for some reason the loading thread is taking too long**. Why not use the time profiler in instruments to find out why?

You'll probably find that the issue is that you are creating a brand new image view every time and adding it as the cells background view.

Creating, adding and removing views is an expensive operation that should not be performed while scrolling. Your custom collection view cells should already have an image view, which you've added in the storyboard or a custom init method, and created an outlet or property for. It's very unusual not to use a subclassed cell, since the base cell has nothing in the content view.

When populating the cell, just set the image view's image property to your stored image. This should be fast enough that you don't need a spinner.

From your comments, it sounds like you also have these problems:

- you are using images that are far too large. For display in a list you must use appropriately sized thumbnail images
- you are performance testing on the simulator. This is irrelevant to real-life app performance on a device. The memory situation is completely different and the speed of things can be faster or slower depending on the operation (usually, CPU-based is faster, but GPU-based is slower).

Comment: I subclassed the cell and not it works a bit faster but not as I want it to be. I will use the time profiler to understand better what's going on.

Comment: could elaborate a bit on how you would do it to track the problem down? I have been using time profiler but honestly I don't usually use so it didn't help much.

Comment: Switch between the sections while the profiler is running. You should see a lot of activity in the graph. Stop the recording, highlight that section of the graph and look at the methods underneath. You should see which methods are taking up the time. There are lots of tutorials around about it.

Comment: You also need to make sure you're doing all this on the main thread - you can't call reloadData on a background thread.

Comment: I have used the allocations tool, and it seems that when I change the segment, the category "ImageIO_jpeg_Data" increases a lot. For instance the first images are : 200kb; 2,25MB; 200kb; 3,67MB;... After the segment switch : 64,34MB; 30,48MB; 45,84MB. Do you have any clue of what might cause this behaviour?

Comment: That sounds like you're using full-sized images straight from the camera to show in your collection view cells - these take up a lot of memory, and will be very slow too. You need to use scaled images - not just huge images in an image view with scaling.

Comment: I dragged them into xcode and I am only testing on simulator. They are not this size (I just saw on finder and they are are 5MB max).

Comment: File size != memory use. Images are compressed on disk, when opened you use full pixel data.

Comment: So what would you advise?

Comment: All my advice is in the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

`dispatch_get_global_queue` get a concurrent dispatch queue in which multiple tasks are run parallel. It is a background queue, UI updating should be performed on mainQueue, so [_myCollection layoutIfNeeded] should be moved into `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`,
updating UI on concurrent background queue will cause weird behaviour such as pausing or freezing.

And you can try this.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

    // do time consuming things here

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self.collectionView reloadData]; 

    });

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self.activityView stopAnimating]; // after collectionView is updated

    });

});
```

Comment: it didn't work: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self.myCollection reloadData];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.spinnerView.hidden = YES;
            [self.myCollection layoutIfNeeded];

        });
        
        
    });

Comment: switch place of layoutIfNeeded and spinnerView.hidden

Comment: It didn't work:  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self.myCollection reloadData];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.myCollection layoutIfNeeded];
            self.spinnerView.hidden = YES;

        });
        
        
    });

Comment: What is the behaviour?

Comment: the same. When I switch from segment[0] to segment[1], it flashes the spinnerView and shows the segment[0] again. After a few seconds, it shows the segment[1]. Is this because I am loading 10 pictures (stored locally outside the coredata?)

Comment: I think that in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method, imageView is created every time a cell is dequeued,you should make imageView as a subview of the cell, then use cell.imageView.image to update the image.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `dispatch_async`, try using `dispatch_sync for _spinnerView.hidden = YES;` on the main queue.

Comment: it didn't work:
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self.myCollection reloadData];
        [self.myCollection layoutIfNeeded];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.spinnerView.hidden = YES;
        });
        
        
    });

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue here was the size of the photos as @jrturton mentions in his answer.
I shortened the size (to about 10s of KBs) and it works smoothly.